# Laravel Echo doesn't work after app name is changed

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo

I'm trying to achieve real time notifications using Pusher and Echo server and it was able to achieve it following a tutorial in Youtube. Below is the code for Echo:

```
userID = $('meta[name="userID"]').attr('content');
        Echo.private('App.User.'+userID).notification((notification) =>{
            this.notifications.push(notification);
        });
```

This code works for me.

But when I change the app name using artisan command `php artisan app:name Real`, my realtime notification doesn't work. Only when i refresh the page the notifications seems to update. Since I changed the app name i edited my echo code to this:

```
userID = $('meta[name="userID"]').attr('content');
        Echo.private('Real.User.'+userID).notification((notification) =>{
            this.notifications.push(notification);
        });
```

I changed App.User to Real.User , still it doesn't work.

I also changed in **channel.php** :

```
Broadcast::channel('Real.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work? Please give me a solution.